# SignalR behind Yarp.ReverseProxy leads to timeout cause server not answering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, proxy, signalr

I have implemented an yarp.reverse proxy server with the code below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpProxy();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("customPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();                    
            });                
        });
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHttpProxy httpProxy)
    {
        // Configure our own HttpMessageInvoker for outbound calls for proxy operations
        var httpClient = new HttpMessageInvoker(new SocketsHttpHandler()
        {
            UseProxy = false,
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.None,
            UseCookies = false
        });

        // Setup our own request transform class
        var transformer = new CustomTransformer(); // or HttpTransformer.Default;
        var requestOptions = new RequestProxyOptions { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100) };

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.Map("/{**catch-all}", async httpContext =>
            {
                httpContext.Request.Headers["Connection"] = "upgrade";
                
                await httpProxy.ProxyAsync(httpContext, "http://192.168.178.80:5000", httpClient, requestOptions, transformer);
                
                var errorFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IProxyErrorFeature>();
                save_log(httpContext.Request.Path, "/", "http://192.168.178.80:5000" + httpContext.Request.Path, "3");
                // Check if the proxy operation was successful
                if (errorFeature != null)
                {
                    var error = errorFeature.Error;
                    var exception = errorFeature.Exception;
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

And in another app a SignalR server following this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

The proxy server works and forwards the request to the signalR server. But the signalR Client is not able to connect to the signalR Server. I always get a Connection disconnected with error

> Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.

in the Java Script console.
But the SSE is connected as you can see in the following browser status report:

> signalr.js:2156 [2021-03-25T13:19:29.970Z] Information: SSE connected to https://localhost:44318/chatHub?id=IqKD6P0NsUY9Is6OSrMusQ

The problem seems to be the Proxy Server because if I call the site directly it works. Has somebody any idea what's wrong with my Proxy and how I can solve it?

Comment: did you solve this problem?